# Angular 2+ HTTPRequests get data from multiple Charts asynchronously in one method for a chart

Tags: angular, asynchronous, httprequest

I have a ngx-chart, where I want to insert some data from 2 or more different Mongodb Tables. So I have to make HTTPRequests to two different routes, because each route queries its own Collection/Tables in mongodb. How can I do this inside one big method to get all the data in one chart? Because the requests are asynchronous, I would have to do the data manipulation for the chart inside the HTTP-Request method... that would be OK if I only query from one route (or one table). But as I have to query from more than 1 table, I would have to wait for one request to finish, do data manipulation and save the data somewhere.. Then I would have to do second request and do all the same again.

How can I do this? The problem is, that as soon as I "quit" one httpRequest method where the data lies, the data seems not to be available anymore...

This is my method for one request as for now:

```
getProduktReservierung(startTime, endTime, DemoID) { 
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:5555/chart/Product/thisprod' + startTime+'.'+endTime+'.' + DemoID)
    .subscribe((res: Response) => {
      this.chartData = res;
      console.log("Produkt Reservation Data:", this.chartData);
      this.dataArray = this.formatDataReservierungen(this.chartData);    
    },
    (err) => {
      if (err.error instanceof Error) {
        console.log('Client-side error occured.');
      } else {
        console.log('Server-side error occured.');
      }
    });
  }
```

The data manipulation and retrieving part is inside .subscribe() method... how should I do now if I query for other tables data and want to have both the data at once together?

Comment: Did my answer worked ?

Comment: somehow I did not get it to work unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [forkjoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html).

It's similar to `promise.all`. Create an array of all `http` request and pass that array into `forkJoin` and `.subscribe()` just like you do in case of single `http` request.